# How do I create a layout w/ a white background, grey border with a triangle arrow - Android

Tags: android, border

How would I replicate this in Android, my general instinct would be to create a regular layout w/ a border, then have 2 layouts that contain a triangle (one the same color as the border + one that's slightly smaller but white and overlap the two), idk if there's an easier way to do that:

[image]

Comment: Try 9-patch http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html .

Comment: Create image and make it the 9 patch image

Answer (score 0):

You can use `9patch` to achieve something like you wanted.

> The Draw 9-patch tool is a WYSIWYG editor that allows you to create
>   bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of
>   the view and the size of the screen. Selected parts of the image are
>   scaled horizontally or vertically based indicators drawn within the
>   image.

A complete guideline can be found here : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reach this, is to set the layout background to that image.

`background="@drawable/template"`

Probably you want to have the area out of the "bubble" transparent, so you will need to save it as PNG.